# Dialog doesn't trigger the dismiss listener on a button press

Tags: android, listener, android-dialog

I would like to display an ok cancel dialog to the user and I would like to know if use pressed ok, cancel, or if he chose to just dismiss the dialog by clicking elsewhere on the screen or pressing back button.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            // ok stuff
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            // cancel stuff
        }
    });
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            //dismiss stuff
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

The problem here is that whenever user presses ok button, dismiss listener gets triggered right after.Is there any way to not trigger dismiss listener if user presses button?

I do realize that I can use a boolean flag, but I am hoping that there is actually an elegant solution.

I am not searching for solution on how to prevent dialog from being dismissed. I am searching for solution on how to prevent dismiss listener from being triggered when ok button is pressed and dialog gets dismissed.

Comment: @ADM how is this duplicate? Did you read the question properly? User just want to **avoid** onDismiss  for Ok and Cancel button press.

Comment: Yeah i read the question properly . And thats what i think . Dismiss Listener will get called anyway .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setOnDismissListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)) will be called for **any reason**. It means if dialog will disappear from the screen either due to Ok/Cancel button press or screen touch or back button or home button press, `setOnDismissListener()` will be called.

> Sets the callback that will be called when the dialog is dismissed for
>   any reason.
>
> If you are interested in listening for all cases where the dialog is
>   dismissed and not just when it is canceled, see [setOnDismissListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener))

So workaround it what you have mentioned, check using some boolean flags and handle it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is [setOnCancelListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnCancelListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `CustomViewDialog` by using

```
LayoutInflater myDialog = getLayoutInflater();
        
View convertView = (View) myDialog.inflate(R.layout.MyLayoutXmlFile, null);
```

Also don't use `positive` or `negative` buttons only use buttons in the dialog layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can again show that dialog after being dismissed!

Comment: There's no reason for you to make two different answers here. Edit your original and remove this one.